# use external .js to call .bind()

Tags: javascript, html, click, bind, external

im trying to call 
.bind("click")
from an external .js file (js1.js).

here is the code:

js1.js:

```
$(function() {
$("p").bind("click",function(){
  alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
});
});
```

page.html:

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./css/mystyle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/global.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/js1.js"></script>
<title>New WebPage</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click me!</p>
</body>
```

this code does not work in my files.

i found it from w3scools and it is working in their site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("p").bind("click",function(){
alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click me!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

how can i make it running from my external .js? any ideas?

thanks.

Comment: i forgot to post an extra "});" in the end of the first file in my question.

Comment: You can use the "edit" button at the bottom of your post to add the missing `})`.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, you haven't added jQuery on your page yet. Add jQuery prior to your script.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./css/mystyle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/global.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/js1.js"></script>
<title>New WebPage</title>
```

Comment: still nothing.
maybe there is something i'm missing on the .js file in the way i'm handling the click function?

Comment: @PantelisGeorgiades check the console. Usually it's F12.

Answer (score 0):

If you forget to add this line

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

so add it in your `<head> </head>` section first. Otherwise your script could not work.
Bellow the complete code which working for me..

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#p').bind('click', function(){
    alert('The paragraph was clicked.');
});
});
</script>
<style>
#p{cursor:pointer;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p id="p">Click me!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: copied it and still nothing. maybe i should alter something in the external .js to make the function operate properly?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
$("p").bind("click",function().html("The paragraph was clicked.");});` you may alter and try this instead of `alert()`

Comment: nothing changed. still doesn't run the function from the external .js

Comment: where? i did not understood what you just said. :/

Comment: This is working for me..    `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function clicks(){
$("p").bind("click",function(){
      $('#p').html("The paragraph was clicked.");
  });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="p"><a onClick="clicks();">Click me!</a></p>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: okay @RajSar this is working just great. i adjust my code to this example and its good. thanks a lot!! :)